# Sharepoint 2013 Metainfo Readable

Tags: sharepoint

I want to ask, how to read field "metainfo" in "alldocs" table, database "WSS_Content" on Share Point 2013
its stored on binarystream format..

i've tried Cast(Cast(metainfo AS varbinary(2048)) As varchar(2048)) but still not working

I want to read this "metainfo" because I need to get the specific content, especially "number of likes"

Please Advice 
Thank you

Comment: I found that content can be inside alldocsstreams but my alldocsstreams was missing from sql server.

Comment: I found that maybe the content is inside alldocstreams but my alldocstreams was missing from sql server. I want to know if sharepoint insert content in alldocstreams or other table. If it is inside alldocstreams, can i get back my missing alldocstreams?, if not, what table contain the content?, thank you